# How to use DashCode for designing a website, especially Browser template of the DashCode?

Tags: dashcode

I am new to DashCode, upto now I used to design websites with JavaScript, HTML, now I want develop website in DashCode for iPhone's mobile safari. but I am really frustrating about DashCode. I started design by taking Browser template of DashCode so I can get navigation which suited for my website. but for detail I am not able to put any thing.

```
can anybody give details about DashCode and Browser template. and please specify some reference books or pdf files for designing iPhone web apps with DashCode.
 Some help from some one really very useful to me. Thanks for help.
```

Comment: Stop Press. There is now a Dashcode for Dummies. I have not looked at it so i have no idea of it's utility but its a help. http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470884738.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly there are no dashcode books, a few make mention in passing but do not shed any light on the subject. They are either sub Apple documentation or just tell you to go to the Apple documentation.

Your next source is apples documentation which is patchy. It deals very much with the subject at a higher level expecting you to only drag and drop in the library and for instance doesn't give you a listing of command calls per se.

Assuming you do not have it this is probably the [starting point](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Dashcode_UserGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/Introduction/Introduction.html) from apple and you really do need to read round the subject to pick items up.

Dashcode is as you allude only html, css and javascript but the trick is to understand the Javascript calls and functions (sorry blindingly obvious i know)

There are other frameworks you can use to do the same thing such as Sencha Touch and IUI. I wrote a blog entry on [these here](http://www.howitt.com/?p=196). And Apple themselves have two other non-released non-documented frameworks called Adlib and Pastrykit that you might want to look at.

I am afraid it is a very confusing and fast moving area, but interesting.

Comment: supplementary to above i see that Sproutcore, used by Apple to build most of Mobile Me and some of iWork has brought out a touch library and an interface builder. And as Cappuccino has now been bought by Motorola we can probably expect a touch library from them in the very near future to help boost Android sales.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not doing any marketing for them but i did finish a video course on "Developing iPhone Web Apps" from VTC a while ago. It was great! Highly recommended!

It's recorded by the same, Jesse Feiler, who wrote Dashcode For Dummies.